# Simple Bat file, Windows cannot find 'nameofthefile'

Tags: windows, batch-file

So i'm trying to create a very simple bat file to run 2 programs. More specifically hearthstone and the deck tracker.

this is my bat:

```
@echo off 
cd "D:\Games\Hearthstone.Deck.Tracker-v0.12.3\Hearthstone Deck Tracker" 
start HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe

cd "D:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone" 
start Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe

exit
```

While Hearthstone launches with no problem, for some reason it can't find the deck tracker exe.
I copy pasted the path directly, it IS correct and the file exists.

Also note that i wrotte a simple code in python 3.5 and both programs open with no problem.

So... what's going on?

Comment: I think you need double quotes: `start "Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe"` because there are spaces in the executable file name.

Comment: @AKS: yep, but you also need an extra argument, otherwise it interprets it as a window title.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cd /d "D:\Games\Hearthstone.Deck.Tracker-v0.12.3\Hearthstone Deck Tracker" 
start HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe

cd /d "D:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone" 
start "Hearthstone Beta Launcher" "Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe"
```

The `/d` option allows `cd` to change drives as well as directories.  The quote marks (and extra argument) are necessary to allow `start` to run a program with spaces in the name.

Comment: I completely agree :)

Comment: If "D:" isn't the current drive, `cd` without `/d` just sets the hidden environment variable `=D:`. This environment variable is used to complete a relative path. Thus without using `/d` you could use `start D:HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe`. To list all environment variables including hidden variables, enter `set "`.

Comment: @eryksun: I may be mistaken, but I don't think `start D:HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe` would set the (actual) current directory as desired.  (I'm assuming these applications need the current directory set to their program directory; if not, there's no need to use `cd` at all.)

Comment: The initial working directory will be inherited from cmd.exe if the `/d` option isn't specified. But why would a program need the working directory set to the application directory? That's redundant (i.e. [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197)) and just plain bad design. If anything a program needs the working directory set to the directory where it's going to write output files, which shouldn't be its own directory since generally a standard user can't modify that directory.

Comment: My initial comment started as just a fun fact about the hidden variables for per-drive current directories. I added the part about `D:HearthstoneDeckTracker.exe` just as an example of how it's used.

Comment: @eryksun: no worries, I just wanted to make sure we didn't mislead anyone.  I agree that applications *shouldn't* need to have any particular current directory set - none of *my* software does - but unfortunately speaking as a sysadmin I've found that such a requirement isn't nearly as uncommon as I'd prefer. :-)

Comment: nope.... windows still insists it can't find the file......................... this is infuriating-_-

Comment: Download Process Monitor from the MS web site and use it to confirm exactly which file isn't being found.